# Permissions for new files in specific folder

Tags: php, apache, symfony, debian, vagrant

I have a Symfony2 application running in apache on a vagrant vm. 
Apache is running as the user `www-data` and php scripts will usually run as the user `vagrant`.

Because caching in a synced folder is slow, I use `/dev/shm/project/cache` and `/dev/shm/project/logs` for my logs.

I set up the permissions like mentioned here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"www-data":rwX -m u:"www-user":rwX -m u:"vagrant":rwX /dev/shm/project/cache /dev/shm/project/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"www-data":rwX -m u:"www-user":rwX -m u:"vagrant":rwX /dev/shm/project/cache /dev/shm/project/logs
```

My problem is that when I run `phpunit` as `vagrant` the cache files are created with the following permissions, which are a problem when accessing them via apache, because it results in a *RuntimeException "Failed to write cache file..."*.

```
$ ls -la /dev/shm/project/cache/test
total 2320
drwxrwxr-x+ 7 vagrant vagrant    400 May 19 12:52 ./
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 root    root        60 May 19 12:52 ../
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 vagrant vagrant  38700 May 19 12:52 annotations/
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant 233164 May 19 12:52 appTestDebugProjectContainerCompiler.log
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant 538934 May 19 12:52 appTestDebugProjectContainer.php
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant  57446 May 19 12:52 appTestDebugProjectContainer.php.meta
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant 847598 May 19 12:52 appTestDebugProjectContainer.xml
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant 174805 May 19 12:52 appTestUrlGenerator.php
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant  16185 May 19 12:52 appTestUrlGenerator.php.meta
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant   5050 May 19 12:52 classes.map
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 vagrant vagrant     60 May 19 12:52 doctrine/
...
```

I don't want to switch the user everytime when I have to run some script. I want the permissions for new files set, so that both users can change them.

**Edit:** There is a third user: `www-user`. This user is the user for fpm. So actually this user and the vagrant user must have the read and write permissions for all files. I already changed the acl, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it adding your current user (`vagrant`?) to the www-data user group, that's the same of the Apache user.

In a similar environment, I used a dedicated user, part of that group.

Comment: Problem is, that group members also cannot `write`

Comment: Apache needs the write permission on the cache dir, or your app will never work.

Comment: Apache has the needed write permission on the cache dir. But it has not the permission to modify (write) on the newly created cache files. This is also the case for the group as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add umask(0002) to .profile at home dir of each 3 users(It is  way for linux, just not sure about VM)

or

> Put the following line at the beginning of the app/console,
>   web/app.php and web/app_dev.php files:
>
> umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775

p.s: all 3 users must belong  www-data user group

Comment: Already tried using `umask 0002` in the .php files and by executing as command before running phpunit. However, my files are still not writeable for the group `-rw-r--r--+ 1 vagrant vagrant  40960 May 20 11:39 test.db`.

Comment: can you try to put umask to .profile config file? so if home dir is /home/vagrant/ then put it to /home/vagrant/.profile , clear cache and run a console command again

Comment: Just did that; and for all other users too. My umask is 0002 and I delete the existing files before running phpunit. Still all created files are `-rw-r--r--`. There is one exception though: Folders are `drwxrwxr-x`